# How change height in navigation title?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I need to set the rockwell-bold font in the navigation title, but it is cropped for me. how can I fix this problem or change the height of the navigation title[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nVgN.png)

Comment: could you please share your code or UI for better explanation / understanding?

Comment: Yes, I add image

Comment: Its my navigation title with rockwell-bold font

Answer (score 0):

```
 let customText = NSLocalizedString("your_title", comment: "")

 let title:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: customText, attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "font_name", size: 20.0) ])

 let size = title.size()

 let width = size.width
        guard let height = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height else {return}

 let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: width, height: height))
 titleLabel.attributedText = title
 titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
 titleLabel.textAlignment = .center

 navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```